# Hyperledger v1.0 - Java SDK and Chaincode deployment

Tags: java, rest, development-environment, blockchain, hyperledger

I have tried to setup Hyperledger V1.0 in our local machines using the Docker-Compose files mentioned in Hackfest. All 6 containers are up and running. When  tried register some chaincode, it was fine too..

But when i try to use REST api from other machine (testing using POSTMAN), i am not getting any results, its throwing some error. I have tried to debug without much success.

let me know, if anyone have tried the same and able to get it working properly. Need some help in setting it up in our local environment for Java based chaincode development.

I have tried docker containers method and followed the instructions from http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/

Comment: Please share steps and output you see :)

Comment: no rest apis since fabric v1.0

Answer (score 0):

from v1.0 , rest seems to be deprecated

Comment: then the only way is using their SDK and write our own REST layer.. right? or is there any alternate way can try?

Comment: Yes but there are good examples of Node sdk and Java, I am looking for Golang API examples, couldn't find some good one

Comment: golang i couldn't find anything either... can you share Node/Java examples you found interesting..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking now but the official go sdk is pretty useful here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go but the one I found incredibly useful for simplicity in getting started is here https://github.com/CognitionFoundry/gohfc if you go into the subdirectories examples/4-apis. It helped me tremendously verifying I had my CA setup correctly.